# Collision detection system not working after porting from Java applet to Android app

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

As I've been porting a java applet I made using [tutorials](http://www.kilobolt.com/day-7-creating-an-android-game-from-start-to-finish.html) from the xda dev site I've run into many issues. I've been trying to bring things over one by one to minimize errors. This collision detection problem has proven to be the issue I can't fix. The way it's supposed to work is by placing rectangles over the bullets shot by the main sprite and also around the enemies. When the rectangles intersect, the bullet should disappear and the enemy should die.

Something tells me android's rectangle functions might be an issue here. As shown in [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) link, there are four different intersection tests. The code I have for the collision detection system is essentially the same as what's used in the tutorials though. Also, I'm not even sure if the rectangles are in the correct places, if they're on the screen at all, since I was unable to draw the rectangles using the "drawRect" function. The tuple values should be right since everything was copied from the desktop game version.

EDIT: Everything was copied from the desktop version, but I had to change everything that had to do with rectangles since I could no longer use java.awt.Rectangle. All rectangle related code uses android.graphics.Rect.

tl;dr: Collision detection brought from java applet to android app with minor changes won't work.

Here's the ported code:

```
package com.kilobolt.robotgame;

import android.graphics.Rect;

public class Projectile {

    private int x, y, speedY;
    private boolean visible;

    private Rect r;

    public Projectile(int startX, int startY) 
    {
        x = startX;
        y = startY;
        speedY = 7;
        visible = true;

        r = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    }

    public void update()
    {
        y -= speedY;
        r.set(x, y, 4, 10);
        if (y < 0) {
           visible = false;
           r=null;
        }
        if (visible){
            checkCollision();
        }
    }

    private void checkCollision()
    {
        if(Rect.intersects(r, GameScreen.xguy1.xrect1) && GameScreen.xguy1IsAlive == true)
        {
        visible = false;
        GameScreen.score += 10;
        GameScreen.xguy1IsAlive = false;
        System.out.println("1st enemy Collision");
        }
        else if(Rect.intersects(r, GameScreen.xguy2.xrect2) && GameScreen.xguy2IsAlive == true)
        {
            visible = false;
            GameScreen.score += 10;
            GameScreen.xguy2IsAlive = false;
            System.out.println("2nd enemy Collision - RIGHT");
        }
        else if(Rect.intersects(r, GameScreen.xguy3.xrect3) && GameScreen.xguy3IsAlive == true)
        {
            visible = false;
            GameScreen.score += 10;
            GameScreen.xguy3IsAlive = false;
            System.out.println("3rd enemy Collision");
        }

        if(GameScreen.xguy1IsAlive == false && GameScreen.xguy2IsAlive == false 
                && GameScreen.xguy3IsAlive == false)
        {
            GameScreen.allEnemiesAreDead = true;
        }

//      if(r.intersect(GameScreen.saucer.sRect))
//      {
//          visible = false;
//          GameScreen.score += 100;
//          GameScreen.saucerIsAlive = false;
//          System.out.println("you hit the alien!");
//      }

    }


    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getSpeedY() {
        return speedY;
    }

    public boolean isVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setSpeedY(int speedY) {
        this.speedY = speedY;
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }

}
```

...................................................

```
package com.kilobolt.robotgame;

import android.graphics.Rect;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Enemy 
{
    private int maxHealth, currentHealth, power, speedX, speedY, centerX, centerY;
    private Background bg = GameScreen.getBg1();
    public  Rect xrect1 = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    public  Rect xrect2 = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    public  Rect xrect3 = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    private boolean isMovingRight = true;
    private boolean isMovingLeft = false;
    private boolean xguy1IsShooting = false;
    private boolean xguy2IsShooting = false;
    private boolean xguy3IsShooting = false;
//  private ArrayList<EnemyProjectile> eProjectiles = new ArrayList<EnemyProjectile>();

    //Behavioral Methods
    public void update() {
    //centerX += speedY;
    //moveRight();
    //moveLeft();
    //changeMovement();
    //autoFire();
    speedY = bg.getSpeedY();
    speedX = 1;
    //setBounds??? 
    xrect1.set(centerX + 74, centerY - 18, 14, 14);
    xrect2.set(centerX + 134, centerY - 18, 14, 14); 
    xrect3.set(centerX + 19 , centerY - 18, 14, 14);
    }

//  public void autoFire()
//  {
//      int num = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((250 - 1) + 1));
//      //System.out.println(num);
//      if(num == 4 || num == 6 || num == 8 && xguy1IsShooting == false)
//      {
//          if(GameScreen.xguy1IsAlive == true)
//          {
//              //xguy1Attack();
//          }
//      }
//      if(num == 1 || num == 3 || num == 5 && xguy2IsShooting == false)
//      {
//          if(GameScreen.xguy2IsAlive == true)
//          {
//              //xguy2Attack();
//          }
//      }
//      if(num == 12 || num == 15 || num == 17 && xguy3IsShooting == false)
//      {
//          if(GameScreen.xguy3IsAlive == true)
//          {
//              //xguy3Attack();
//          }
//      }
//  }

    public void moveRight()
    {
        if(isMovingRight == true)
        {
            centerX += speedX;
            if(centerX >= 630)
            {
                isMovingRight = false;
                isMovingLeft = true;
            }
        }
    }
    public void moveLeft()
    {
        if(isMovingLeft == true)
        {
            centerX -= speedX;
            if(centerX <= 10)
            {
                isMovingLeft = false;
                isMovingRight = true;
            }
        }
    }
    public void changeMovement()
    {
        //causes delayed death - xguys only die after going right
        if(centerX >= 630)
        {
            isMovingRight = false;
        }
        if(isMovingRight == false)
        {
            isMovingLeft = true;
        }
    }
    public void die() 
    {

    }
//  public void xguy1Attack() 
//  {
//      EnemyProjectile e = new EnemyProjectile(centerX - 10, centerY - 6);
//      eProjectiles.add(e);
//      xguy1IsShooting = false;
//  }
//  public void xguy2Attack()
//  {
//      EnemyProjectile e = new EnemyProjectile(centerX + 50, centerY - 6);
//      eProjectiles.add(e);
//      xguy2IsShooting = false;
//  }
//  
//  public void xguy3Attack()
//  {
//      EnemyProjectile e = new EnemyProjectile(centerX - 70, centerY - 6);
//      eProjectiles.add(e);
//      xguy3IsShooting = false;
//  }

    public int getMaxHealth() {
        return maxHealth;
    }

    public int getCurrentHealth() {
        return currentHealth;
    }

    public int getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public int getSpeedY() {
        return speedY;
    }

    public int getCenterX() {
        return centerX;
    }

    public int getCenterY() {
        return centerY;
    }

    public Background getBg() {
        return bg;
    }

    public void setMaxHealth(int maxHealth) {
        this.maxHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    public void setCurrentHealth(int currentHealth) {
        this.currentHealth = currentHealth;
    }

    public void setPower(int power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    public void setSpeedX(int speedX) {
        this.speedY = speedX;
    }

    public void setCenterX(int centerX) {
        this.centerX = centerX;
    }

    public void setCenterY(int centerY) {
        this.centerY = centerY;
    }

    public void setBg(Background bg) {
        this.bg = bg;
    }

//  public ArrayList getEProjectiles() {
//      return eProjectiles;
//      }
}
```

.......................................................

```
package com.kilobolt.robotgame;

import com.kilobolt.robotgame.BasicEnemy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;

import com.kilobolt.framework.Game;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Graphics;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Image;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Input.TouchEvent;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Screen;

public class GameScreen extends Screen {
    enum GameState {
        Ready, Running, Paused, GameOver
    }

    GameState state = GameState.Ready;

    // Variable Setup

    private static Background bg1, bg2;
    private static Ship ship;
    public static BasicEnemy xguy1, xguy2, xguy3;
//
    private Image character, damaged1, damaged2, background, startScreen, xguy, vxguy, explode1, explode2, explode3, explode4, explode5,
    explode6, explode7, explode8, explode9, explode10, explode11, explode12, xexplode, xexplode2, flyingSaucer;
    private Animation anim, xanim;

    public static int score = 0;
    public static int lives = 3;

    static boolean xguy1IsAlive = true;
    static boolean xguy2IsAlive = true;
    static boolean xguy3IsAlive = true;

    static boolean saucerIsAlive = true;
    static boolean allEnemiesAreDead = false;

    static boolean saucerTime = false;
    static boolean saucerIsMoving = false; 
    static boolean startScreenOn = true;

    Paint paint, paint2;

    public GameScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);

        // Initialize game objects here

        bg1 = new Background(0, 0);
        bg2 = new Background(0, -480);
        ship = new Ship();
        xguy1 = new BasicEnemy(420, 100);
        xguy2 = new BasicEnemy(480, 100);
        xguy3 = new BasicEnemy(360, 100);

        character = Assets.character;
        damaged1 = Assets.character2;
        damaged1 = Assets.character3;

        xguy = Assets.xguy;

        xanim = new Animation();
        xanim.addFrame(xguy, 250);
        xanim.addFrame(vxguy, 250);

        // Defining a paint object
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextSize(30);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        paint2 = new Paint();
        paint2.setTextSize(100);
        paint2.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    }


    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();

        if (state == GameState.Ready)
            updateReady(touchEvents);
        if (state == GameState.Running)
            updateRunning(touchEvents, deltaTime);
        if (state == GameState.Paused)
            updatePaused(touchEvents);
        if (state == GameState.GameOver)
            updateGameOver(touchEvents);
    }

    private void updateReady(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {

        // This example starts with a "Ready" screen.
        // When the user touches the screen, the game begins.
        // state now becomes GameState.Running.
        // Now the updateRunning() method will be called!

        if (touchEvents.size() > 0)
            state = GameState.Running;
    }

    private void updateRunning(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents, float deltaTime) {

        // This is identical to the update() method

        // 1. All touch input is handled here:
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {

                if (inBounds(event, 735, 415, 65, 65)) {
                    ship.moveRight();
                    ship.setMovingRight(true);
                    System.out.println("sucess");
                }
                if (inBounds(event, 0, 415, 65, 65)) {
                    ship.moveLeft();
                    ship.setMovingLeft(true);
                    System.out.println("sucess");
                }               
                else if (inBounds(event, 0, 350, 65, 65)) {
                    ship.shoot();
                }
                else if (inBounds(event, 735, 350, 65, 65)) {
                    ship.shoot();
                }
//              else if (inBounds(event, 0, 415, 65, 65)
//                      ) {
////                    currentSprite = Assets.characterDown;
////                    robot.setDucked(true);
////                    robot.setSpeedX(0);
//
//              }

                if (event.x > 400) {
                    //...

                }

            }

            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {

                if (inBounds(event, 0, 415, 65, 65)) {
//                  //...

                }
                if (inBounds(event, 735, 415, 65, 65)) {
                    ship.stopRight();
                }
                if (inBounds(event, 0, 415, 65, 65)) {
                    ship.stopLeft();
                }

//              if (inBounds(event, 0, 0, 35, 35)) {
//                  pause();
//
//              }

                if (event.x > 400) {
                    //...
                }
            }

        }

        // 2. Check miscellaneous events like death:
//
//      if (livesLeft == 0) {
//          state = GameState.GameOver;
//      }

        // 3. Call individual update() methods here.
        // This is where all the game updates happen.
        ship.update();

        ArrayList projectiles = ship.getProjectiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++) {
            Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
            if (p.isVisible() == true) {
                p.update();
            } else {
                projectiles.remove(i);
            }
        }


        xguy1.update();
        xguy2.update();
        xguy3.update();
        bg1.update();
        bg2.update();
        animate();
//...game over state here...
    }

    private boolean inBounds(TouchEvent event, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) {
        if (event.x > x && event.x < x + width - 1 && event.y > y
                && event.y < y + height - 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private void updatePaused(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
                if (inBounds(event, 0, 0, 800, 240)) {

                    if (!inBounds(event, 0, 0, 35, 35)) {
                        resume();
                    }
                }

                if (inBounds(event, 0, 240, 800, 240)) {
                    nullify();
                    goToMenu();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateGameOver(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {
                if (inBounds(event, 0, 0, 800, 480)) {
                    nullify();
                    game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(float deltaTime) {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

        g.drawImage(Assets.background, bg1.getBgX(), bg1.getBgY());
        g.drawImage(Assets.background, bg2.getBgX(), bg2.getBgY());

        ArrayList projectiles = ship.getProjectiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++) {
            Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
            g.drawRect(p.getX()-34, p.getY()+10, 4, 10, Color.RED);
        }
//      // First draw the game elements.
//
        g.drawImage(Assets.character, ship.getCenterX() - 24,
                ship.getCenterY() - 24);
        if(xguy1IsAlive == true)
        {
            g.drawImage(xanim.getImage(), xguy1.getCenterX()-16, xguy1.getCenterY()-12);
        }
        if(xguy2IsAlive == true)
        {
            g.drawImage(xanim.getImage(), xguy2.getCenterX()-16, xguy2.getCenterY()-12);
        }
        if(xguy3IsAlive == true)
        {
            g.drawImage(xanim.getImage(), xguy3.getCenterX()-16, xguy3.getCenterY()-12);
        }
        g.drawRect(xguy1.getCenterX() + 74, xguy1.getCenterX() - 18, 14,  14, 0);

        // Example:
        // g.drawImage(Assets.background, 0, 0);
        // g.drawImage(Assets.character, characterX, characterY);

        // Secondly, draw the UI above the game elements.
        if (state == GameState.Ready)
            drawReadyUI();
        if (state == GameState.Running)
            drawRunningUI();
        if (state == GameState.Paused)
            drawPausedUI();
        if (state == GameState.GameOver)
            drawGameOverUI();

    }

    public void animate() {
        //anim.update(10);
        xanim.update(50);
    }

    private void nullify() {

        // Set all variables to null. You will be recreating them in the
        // constructor.
        paint = null;
        bg1 = null;
        bg2 = null;
        ship = null;
        xguy1 = null;
        xguy2 = null;
        xguy3 = null;
//      currentSprite = null;
        character = null;
        damaged1 = null;
        damaged2 = null;
        xguy = null;
        vxguy = null;
//      anim = null;
        xanim = null;

        // Call garbage collector to clean up memory.
        System.gc();

    }

    private void drawReadyUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

        g.drawARGB(155, 0, 0, 0);
        g.drawString("Tap to Start.", 400, 240, paint);

    }

    private void drawRunningUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(Assets.right, 735, 415, 0, 0, 65, 65);
        g.drawImage(Assets.left, 0, 415, 0, 0, 65, 65);
        g.drawImage(Assets.reticle, 0, 350, 0, 0, 65, 65);
        g.drawImage(Assets.reticle, 735, 350, 0, 0, 65, 65);
    }

    private void drawPausedUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        // Darken the entire screen so you can display the Paused screen.
        g.drawARGB(155, 0, 0, 0);
        g.drawString("Resume", 400, 165, paint2);
        g.drawString("Menu", 400, 360, paint2);

    }

    private void drawGameOverUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 1281, 801, Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("GAME OVER.", 400, 240, paint2);
        g.drawString("Tap to return.", 400, 290, paint);

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        if (state == GameState.Running)
            state = GameState.Paused;

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        if (state == GameState.Paused)
            state = GameState.Running;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public void backButton() {
        pause();
    }

    private void goToMenu() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));

    }

    public static Background getBg1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return bg1;
    }

    public static Background getBg2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return bg2;
    }

    public static Ship getShip() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ship;
    }

}
```

Comment: what rectangle class is used in your original Java applet?

Comment: @talkol I used java.awt.Rectangle

Comment: Older Android phones don't have the same support for floating point as PCs do.  I suggest you make sure you have enough tolerance for floating point error.

Comment: I bet that your issues are because of the API difference between the 2 rectangle classes. Comparing http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html I see some differences such as the meaning of ctor arguments

Comment: I don't know about that. Like I mentioned in the post, the collision detection system in my ported code is essentially the same as what's used in the tutorial's ported code (which worked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that your issues are because of the API difference between the 2 rectangle classes.

Comparing [android.graphics.Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and [java.awt.Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) I see some differences such as the meaning of method arguments.

For example, the android Rect uses left and **right** and the awt Rectangle uses left and **width**.

In your code in class `Projectile` function `update` you call `r.set(..)` and I'm pretty sure you're passing width and height as the last arguments instead of right and bottom.

So your existing code:

```
r.set(x, y, 4, 10);
```

Should be ported to:

```
r.set(x, y, x+4, y+10);
```

Comment: I'd go further than that/  Why even use awt?

Comment: @talkol I tried that before and it didn't work. I tried again just in case and it still doesn't work. Thanks though. Simon, the ported code doesn't use awt. Also, what would you do to try to fix this issue? I'm stuck, so all help is welcome.

Comment: The original code for the collision detection is almost exactly the same, except I used awt, "Rect" is "Rectangle", "set" is "setRect", and and the intersection test is "if(r.intersects(StartingClass.xguy1.xrect1) && StartingClass.xguy1IsAlive == true)"

Comment: I'm pretty sure you only need to modify all of your set calls so the last two parameters are not width and height but right and top. This goes for r.set(..) in Projectile.update() and in Enemy.update() you have 3 calls which need to be fixed.